What connector for mounting a CR435 battery to PCB?
I'm designing a small device (lighted arrow nock) powered by a CR435 pin battery, which looks like this. The pin at the top (1.0mm diameter) is the negative terminal, and the body (4.0mm diameter) is the positive:

I'm having trouble finding some way to connect this to the PCB. I was thinking of maybe using a fuse holder (at least for the positive connection), but I'm further restricted that the whole thing should fit in around 6mm (the inside diameter of an arrow).
I'm also okay with just connecting the pin and simply wrapping a wire around the body. And it doesn't necessarily have to be held tight either, it just needs to make proper contact. I don't want to solder directly to the pin either, since the battery should be easy to change.

What is a "lighted arrow nock"?

@jonathanjo An arrow nock is the part at the tail of the arrow which attaches to the bowstring. Lighted nocks are useful in low-light conditions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nf4PrtGaIMA

I confess to not having much specialist archery vocabulary!


As D-type pins are 1 mm diameter, I'd expect any D-type female connector to work with the negative terminal.
As (some) bullet crimp connectors are 3.96 mm, I'd expect any bullet female connector to work with the positive.

I'm imagining you connect these to wires which solder to your PCB, and then they slide onto your battery.
Here's one from Molex, but obviously there are very many manufacturers and endless styles (crimp, solder, etc):

Molex web site

